# Spring Boot and OAuth2 social login, unable to get refreshToken

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-social, spring-oauth2

There is a guide how to implement OAuth2 using Spring and Spring Boot https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

I need to store OAuth2 information like accessToken, refreshToken in my database for future use. Right now I can only get accessToken. I can't figure out how to get refreshToken based on this guide.

What is the proper way to get refreshToken using approach described in this guide ?

**UPDATED**

I have an access to `refreshToken` in `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication` method but only `accessToken` is paased to `ResourceServerTokenServices.loadAuthentication` method.

Right now I don't understand how to get OAuth2 information based on this approach after successful authorization in Facebook and to reuse it for Facebook API calls. Please advise.

**UPDATED**

I have added `JdbcClientTokenServices` to my SSO filter but it doesn't work

```
private Filter ssoFilter(ClientResources client, String path) {
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter clientFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(path);
        OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(client.getClient(), oauth2ClientContext);

        //
        AccessTokenProviderChain tokenProviderChain = new AccessTokenProviderChain(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider())));
        tokenProviderChain.setClientTokenServices(new JdbcClientTokenServices(dataSource));
        oAuth2RestTemplate.setAccessTokenProvider(tokenProviderChain);
        //

        clientFilter.setRestTemplate(oAuth2RestTemplate);
        clientFilter.setTokenServices(new OkUserInfoTokenServices(okService, client.getClient().getClientId(), apiUrl, eventService));
        clientFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new UrlParameterAuthenticationHandler());
        return clientFilter;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: when working with OAuth2 it is necessary to have a good understanding of how the protocol works. It's not too difficult, but you need to have a good grasp of it to be able to work with it. In my opinion the best point of reference is the specification itself: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749

In response to the conversation below and the existing pull request https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/pull/499 I would (as long as the pull request isn't released) subclass OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter and include the changes as per pull request, then use that class in the ssoFilter method.

Thus:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.ClientTokenServices;

public class OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingAndSavingFilter extends OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    private ClientTokenServices clientTokenServices;

    public OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingAndSavingFilter(String defaultFilterProcessesUrl, ClientTokenServices clientTokenServices) {
        super(defaultFilterProcessesUrl);
        this.clientTokenServices = clientTokenServices;
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
        if (clientTokenServices != null) {
            clientTokenServices.saveAccessToken(restTemplate.getResource(), SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                    .getAuthentication(), restTemplate.getAccessToken());
        }
    }

}
```

and

```
private Filter ssoFilter(ClientResources client, String path) {
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingAndSavingFilter clientFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingAndSavingFilter(path, clientTokenService);
       ...
```

and add a bean for your clientTokenService

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand how the protocol works and also I understand that I don't need to perform addition(redundant) call to OAuth2 provider in order to fetch `refreshToken`. This information was already shipped to the client but I can't access it. I have only access to plain `String accessToken` in my `ResourceServerTokenServices.loadAuthentication` method instead of a reference to a full `OAuth2AccessToken` object where `refreshToken` can also be found.

Comment: Ah ok, I misunderstood the question then. Maybe you could describe your setup a little bit further. It seems a bit strange that you try to get information on the refresh token on the resource server. Usually only the client and authorization server should need to work with refresh tokens.

Comment: I have implemented SSO via social network(Odnoklassniki) based on the example mentioned above. Right now I'd like to access social network API based on the `accessToken` retrieved during the sign-on process. Also I need the `refreshToken` in order to get new `accessToken` when a previous one is expired. Also I plan to store both - `accessToken`  and `refreshToken`  in my database for the future use.

Comment: Ok. In that case you are acting as the OAuth 'client'. Instead of the `ResourceServerTokenServices` interface you should look at `ClientTokenServices`. Spring Security OAuth2 already comes with a JDBC implementation for this that allows to save the data in a database: `JdbcClientTokenServices`. The OAuth 2.0 Client section on http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html has further info on configuration of a client.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question where I added `JdbcClientTokenServices` but it still doesn't work. Where I'm wrong ?

Comment: Finally I got it working but I'm not sure I got in in the right way. I have updated my question. Please advise me with a more correct approach if exists.

Comment: Found the same issue at GitHub:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/498
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/pull/499

Comment: Looking at the pull request and the original code of `successfulAuthentication` in `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter` (which already contains the comment '...if there is a ClientTokenServices then the token will now be stored') it seems like saving the token has simply been forgotten in the released version. The suggested solution seems fine to me.