# How to restrict to a specific domain to login with Spring-Boot and OAuth2

Tags: java, spring, oauth, spring-boot

I have successfully done a OAuth2 login with spring boot and Google, but I'd like to restrict logins to a specific domain (we're using Google Apps for Work).

I think that I should handle by extending class OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter (as specified [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855468/spring-boot-and-oauth2-social-login-unable-to-get-refreshtoken)), but I'm not sure how to do that.

Basically, I'd like to use Google OAuth 2.0 as the identity provider, but only company users (@company.com) must be accepted.

Comment: One thing you could do is define a bean of type `AuthoritiesExtractor` and do that check there (throwing an appropriate exception if the type of the email doesn't match

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Stéphane suggestion, I came to this [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/), and finally implemented this, which works for me with a Google+ profile:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String GOOGLE_PLUS_DOMAIN_ATTRIBUTE = "domain";
    private static final String CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "XSRF-TOKEN";
    private static final String CSRF_HEADER_NAME = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";

    @Bean
    public AuthoritiesExtractor authoritiesExtractor(
            @Value("#{'${security.allowed-domains}'.split(',')}") final List<String> allowedDomains) {

        return new AuthoritiesExtractor() {
            @Override
            public List<GrantedAuthority> extractAuthorities(final Map<String, Object> map) {
                if (map != null && map.containsKey(GOOGLE_PLUS_DOMAIN_ATTRIBUTE)) {
                    final String domain = (String) map.get(GOOGLE_PLUS_DOMAIN_ATTRIBUTE);
                    if (!allowedDomains.contains(domain)) {
                        throw new BadCredentialsException("Not an allowed domain");
                    }
                    return AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_USER");
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.antMatcher("/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/logout", "/api/mappings/**", "/public/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
        .and().logout().logoutUrl("/api/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")
        .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).ignoringAntMatchers("/api/mappings/**")
        .and().addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
        // @formatter:on
    }

    private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
        return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
                    final FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

                final CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
                if (csrf != null) {
                    Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, CSRF_COOKIE_NAME);
                    final String token = csrf.getToken();
                    if (cookie == null || token != null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                        cookie = new Cookie(CSRF_COOKIE_NAME, token);
                        cookie.setPath("/");
                        response.addCookie(cookie);
                    }
                }
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        };
    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        final HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName(CSRF_HEADER_NAME);
        return repository;
    }
}
```

My application.yml file contains the following entries regarding oauth:

```
security:
     oauth2:
         client:
                access-token-uri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token
                user-authorization-uri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
                client-authentication-scheme: form
                scope: profile,email
         resource:
                user-info-uri: https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
                prefer-token-info: false
```

When working with a Google+ profile, the resource server response provided in the map, contains an entry for domain. I just compared this value with configured allowed domains.

Hope this helps.

Update: On March 7th 2019, Google is deprecating Google+ APIs. If you're like me, you'll have received an email from Google suggesting to update your software. In our case, the url https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me, will be deprecated. So, I'm posting here my updated configuration (build with Spring Boot 1.3.5).

```
security:
 oauth2:
     client:
            clientId: *your client id from Google*
            clientSecret: *your client secret from Google*                
            accessTokenUri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
            userAuthorizationUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
            clientAuthenticationScheme: form
            scope: 
              - email
              - profile                
     resource:
            userInfoUri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo
            preferTokenInfo: false

 # Comma-separated list of domains                
 allowed-domains: *your allowed domains*
```

Please note that minor change must be done in you WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as the attribute domain has changed its name. So you'll need to replace the line:

private static final String GOOGLE_PLUS_DOMAIN_ATTRIBUTE = "domain";

with

private static final String HOSTED_DOMAIN_ATTRIBUTE = "hd";

Comment: this code ins't called in my login process. Maybe I have to configure something else?

Comment: Hi Fernando. Have you defined a custom WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and annotated it with EnableOAuth2Sso?. Please take a look at the examples available in the link I mentioned above.

Comment: Hi @FernandoM.Pinheiro,  I know this thread is very old, but I'm having the same issue.  Just wondered if you remember how you resolved it?

I've defined an AuthoritiesExtractor but it's not being picked up.

Comment: Thank you @JuanCarlosGonzález

Answer (score 0):

I found new solution! You should choose one: **non-reactive** or **reactive** case it's important don't forget:

**non-reactive:**

```
@Bean
fun oauth2UserService(rest: WebClient): OAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> {
    val delegate = DefaultOAuth2UserService()
    return OAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> { request ->
        val user = delegate.loadUser(request)
        val hd = user.getAttribute<String>("hd")
        if (hd == "your.domain.name")
            user
        else
            throw OAuth2AuthenticationException(OAuth2Error("invalid_token", "Not in the Team", ""))
    }
}
```

**reactive:**

```
@Bean
fun oauth2UserService(rest: WebClient): ReactiveOAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> {
    val delegate = DefaultOAuth2UserService()
    return ReactiveOAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> { request ->
        val user = delegate.loadUser(request)
        val hd = user.getAttribute<String>("hd")
        if (hd == "your.domain.name")
            Mono.just(user)
        else
            throw OAuth2AuthenticationException(OAuth2Error("invalid_token", "Not in the Team", ""))
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting! I do not have the code to evaluate your solution, but it seems to be a more cleaner (and I hope, correct) way to do that! Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `?hd=acme.com` to your authorization uri, and Google will restrict the domain for you, and users will only see one domain, not their personal accounts.

Comment: Interesting! I cannot validate right now, but it seems cleaner :-)