# How to restrict a specific domain to login with Spring-Boot and OAuth2 withouth AuthoritiesExtractor?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

There was a way to restrict the domain with class AuthoritiesExtractor:

[How to restrict to a specific domain to login with Spring-Boot and OAuth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37264739/how-to-restrict-to-a-specific-domain-to-login-with-spring-boot-and-oauth2)

But the class was eliminated from spring-security.

What would be the solution with spring-security-5.* versions?

Comment: I believe you are looking for this, 

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2login-advanced-map-authorities-grantedauthoritiesmapper

Which can be plugged into an OAuth UserDetails flow

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly the same behavior I obtain because I don't succeed to prevent to login with another account but I prevent to get the required USER role with such approach:

```
@Configuration
public static class OAuth2WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .........
            .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
            .userInfoEndpoint()
            .oidcUserService(this.oidcUserService());
    }

    private OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> oidcUserService() {
        final OidcUserService delegate = new OidcUserService();

        return (userRequest) -> {
            // Delegate to the default implementation for loading a user
            OidcUser oidcUser = delegate.loadUser(userRequest);
            Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();

            // Map the authority information to one or more GrantedAuthority's and add it to mappedAuthorities
            if (StringUtils.endsWithIgnoreCase(oidcUser.getEmail(), "myDomain.com")) {
                mappedAuthorities.addAll(AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER"));
            } else {
                mappedAuthorities.addAll(AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ANONYMOUS"));
            }    

            // Create a copy of oidcUser but use the mappedAuthorities instead
            oidcUser = new DefaultOidcUser(mappedAuthorities, oidcUser.getIdToken(), oidcUser.getUserInfo());

            return oidcUser;
        };
    }

}
```

I did that based on this [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2login-advanced-map-authorities-oauth2userservice) but I'm not completely satisfied because the user can authenticate (even if he cannot do anything) and I need now to provide a logout function to allow to switch back to the right account if the user used another Google account by error.

HTH