# OAUTH: Only allow users with specific email address (domain) to sign in

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am using the dependencies *spring-security-oauth2-client* and *spring-security-oauth2-jose* with the following code:

```java
@Configuration
public class AuthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

This allows the users to sign in with their Google account. For now, everyone can sign in who has a Google account but I would like to only allow users who have *@example.com email addresses. How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37680108/4913145) response can help you.